# How to create Custom Response Handler in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have **approximately 50 spring controllers** that can return **null** in the response. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl.controller", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object getObject(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    Object object = provider.getObject(id);
    if (object == null ) {
        return throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionDetails handleEntityNotFound(EntityNotFoundException e) {
    return createErrorJsonView(e);
}
```

My goal is to avoid **null checking for each controllers** and **create some general exception handler** for such cases.

As I understand overriding **HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler** spring handler it is not good idea.

Will you have any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You could perform the null checking in the `provider.getObject(id)` function and throw the exception from there.

Comment: What's wrong with this `@ExceptionHandler`? Or is it that you don't want to go refactor all your handlers to `throw` a `EntityNotFoundException`? You should consider the fact that returning `null` is valid in some cases.

Comment: Actually, I guess that I should always handle such cases when returning null, because spring converted this null to empty response. In fact I have issues with jquery library, because it expected to get something that can be parsed. Mo goal is to just avoid null checking in all controllers. In this case I can create some general error handler using @ControllerAdvice annotation.

Comment: Also, I have a lot of different DAOs classes and another manager. So as result I cant handle this behaviour in provider.getObject(id) function.

Answer (score 0):

For the exception handler, you a @ControllerAdvice object and register your handler there:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) 
    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public @ResponseBody ExceptionDetails handleEntityNotFound(EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return createErrorJsonView(e);
    }

}
```

You can find more details here:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Similarly you should explore using an @Initbinder to hydrate and validate your model object.

Comment: Actulaly I know how to create global handler, the question is how to avoid null checking in all controllers.